# Pytube3 stops working after python file is compiled to an .exe

Tags: python, compilation, exe, pyinstaller, pytube

I am writing a youtube downloader script using Pytube3.
I am using an edited version of pytube3, which removes the issues of some videos not being downloaded:
https://github.com/nficano/pytube/pull/631/commits/ad1485ccd503f292fffa6989412fa4843edd0118#diff-bc809824a75c161c999a237c2fdeedf4

Before implementing this edit I would get a `'cyther'` error on 90% of the videos, however after implementing this everything is downloaded.
Everything works fine until I compile the file to an exe using pyinstaller.

I use the following command to compile `pyinstaller dw.py --onefile -i icon.ico`
When the exe is run around 90% of the videos return a `'cyther'` error.

I have tried making a copy of the edited library and putting it in the project directory and importing it from there but that didn't help one bit.

Here is my code: https://github.com/OreoCookey/YTDW/tree/master

Thanks in advance!